# Bind to size of element (div)

Tags: angular

I have a component with Width and Height properties. How can I bind component's view height and width to these properties?

I need them to be updated whenever component size changes too, i.e. by re-sizing the browser window.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use `(window:resize)="onResize($event)"` to listen to global events. You can use `window`, `document` or `body` as targets. See [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/s6kz3Kz50uvnXmv2HbUo?p=preview)

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div 
      class="square"
      [style.width.px]="width" 
      [style.height.px]="height"
      (window:resize)="onResize($event)"
    ></div>
  `
})
export class App {
  width = 100;
  height = 100;

  onResize(event) {
    this.width += 100;
    this.height += 100;
  }
}
```