# Unable to position angular material mat-card using flex layout

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I am new to Flex Layout and just started studying how to use angular material with flex layout.

I have implemented a simple login form in angular 2 using angular material. I want to use flex layout with angular material.

I used mat-card in which i have aligned my form elements. But i want to position mat-card at the centre of my screen.Its getting centred horizontally but not vertically

This is my code

### myform.component.html

```
<div fxlayout="column" style="background: white;">

<mat-card fxFlex>   
            <form  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(user.username,user.password)" #myForm="ngForm">

                                <p style="font-size: 30x;">Space Study</p>
                                <p style="font-size: 14px;">Sign In</p>
                                <mat-input-container class="form-row">
                                    <span matTooltip="Username">
                                        <input matInput placeholder=" " id="username" [(ngModel)]="user.username" name="username">
                                    </span>
                                    <span matPrefix><mat-icon>person&nbsp;&nbsp;</mat-icon></span>
                                </mat-input-container>

                                <mat-input-container class="form-row">
                                    <span matTooltip="Password">
                                        <input matInput placeholder=" " id="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" name="gpassword" [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'">
                                    </span>
                                    <span matPrefix><mat-icon>remove_red_eye&nbsp;&nbsp;</mat-icon></span>
                                </mat-input-container>

                    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" mat-raised-button>Login</button>

                    <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate" *ngIf="showprogressbar"></mat-progress-bar>
            </form>

</mat-card>

</div>
```

### myform.component.css

```
mat-card{
    width: 350px;
    height: 400px;
    margin:auto;  
    vertical-align:middle;  
}

.form-row{
    display: flex;
}

.form-row input{
    flex: 1;
}
```

### Here is my output window

[image]

Can anybody please tell me how can i place my mat-card in the centre of my screen both horizontally and vertically.?

Comment: I was trying to solve the same problem, but could not get vertical centering  to work with flex-layout - finally I found this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33842333/bind-to-size-of-element-div/33847414 which worked out fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I created stackblitz for your question.

[Here is the stackblitz just I changed to the css](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tmd3fi?file=app%2Fstepper-overview-example.ts)

To the css I added.

```
mat-card{
    width: 350px;
    height: 400px;
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.form-row{
    display: flex;
}

.form-row input{
    flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: its same top aligned ,, but not centered

Comment: You can see I edited the answer and put another stackblitz. there is working good.

Answer (score 0):

You can align mat-card to center by updating first two html lines with below code

```
 <div fxlayout="row" style="background: white;height: 100vh;">

   <mat-card fxFlex fxLayoutAlign="center center" style="max-width: 350px; max-height: 200px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the quick and dirty solution with position:absolute like this:

```
mat-card {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```